# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un registro que tenga un valor de columna que no se repita en otro registro? (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, sql, subconsultas

Tengo una consulta aparentemente sencilla que dice:

Seleccionar los clientes que hayan comprado coches solo al concesionario 1.

[image: tabla ventas]
cifcl es cliente
cifc es concesionario

Hice:

```
select  cifc, codcoche, cifcl from venta where  cifc=1
```

Pero el cliente 1 ha comprado también al concesionario 2, así que ¿cómo puedo obtener solo al cliente 2 que sería el resultado correcto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lógica de conjuntos, debes seleccionar la respuesta de dos tipos de conjuntos de resultados, exceptuando un grupo. `Postgresql` te permite hacer [`EXCEPT`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-except/)

Se debe realizar una consulta que obtenga: TODOS los clientes que hayan comprado coches al concesionario 1:

`select  cifc, codcoche, cifcl from venta where  cifc=1`

Después debes realizar una consulta que obtenga: TODOS los clientes que hayan comprado coches de otros concesionarios distintos al 1:

`select  cifc, codcoche, cifcl from venta where  cifc <> 1`

Entonces obtendrás el resultado esperado utilizando `EXCEPT`:

`(select  cifc, codcoche, cifcl from venta where  cifc=1) EXCEPT (select  cifc, codcoche, cifcl from venta where  cifc <> 1)`

Comment: Buscaba hacer algo similar, solo que no conocía el uso del EXCEPT, las demás respuestas me parece que fuerzan el resultado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Aplica el uso de `ORDER BY` y un `LIMIT 1` para poder manipular la forma y cantidad en la que regresan los datos y poder mostrar solo los que son necesarios

**ESCENARIO PREVIO**

Dado que si hacemos una consulta regular como la siguiente

```
SELECT cifcl, codcoche, cifc FROM demo WHERE cifc = 1;
```

Obtenemos un resultado como este

```
cifcl   codcoche    cifc
1          1         1
2          5         1
```

**PROPUESTA DE SOLUCIÓN**

Pero como deseamos al cliente con `id` 2 por que es el único que solo le ha comprado al concesionario 1; entonces podemos hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT cifcl, codcoche, cifc FROM demo WHERE cifc = 1 ORDER BY cifcl DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Obteniendo el resultado esperado

```
cifcl   codcoche    cifc
2          5          1
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Con `ORDER BY columna DESC` logramos invertir el orden que tienen los valores, es decir poner al inicio de la lista de resultados el registro con `id` mas reciente
2. Con `LIMIT 1` hacemos que de los 2 resultados solo tome el primero para el conjunto de resultados que va a mostrar la consola de PostgreSQL dejando visible solo aquel que deseamos

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, se quiere saber qué cliente `cifcl` (en este caso 2) compró en un determinado concesionario `cifc` (en este caso 1)

En el `query` que se ha compartido, correspondiente a la tabla `venta`, se tendría que incluir `AND` con el `WHERE` para que la consulta tome las dos columnas precitadas como referencia:

```
SELECT cifcl, codcoche, cifc
FROM venta
WHERE (cifc=2 AND cifcl=1);
```

Tendrías para la tabla `venta` de seis filas posteada lo siguiente:

```
cifcl, codcoche, cifc
2      5         1
```

Ya que las comparaciones dentro de `(cifc=2 AND cifcl=1)` tienen que ser verdaderas para que el `WHERE` arroje algo.

Si el cliente `2` ha comprado en el mismo concesionario `1` más de una vez -lo cual podría ser poco probable- se puede limitar la búsqueda con `LIMIT n` dónde `n` es la cantidad máxima de filas que deseas consultar *per se*, siendo `WHERE` quien en última instancia condicione si las filas son exactamente el `n` definido en `LIMIT` o menor:

```
SELECT cifcl, codcoche, cifc
FROM venta
WHERE (cifc=2 AND cifcl=1)
LIMIT n; /* n = 1,2,3,4,...
            Si "n" fuera 1 y la condición en 'WHERE' fuera falsa
            no se mostrarían filas, por eso se indicó
            que 'WHERE' condiciona en última instancia a 'LIMIT' */
```